# onmouseover with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I have an anchor tag wherein I have `mouseover` and `mouseout` function.

CSS:

```
.pt   #showdata
{
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    left:350px;
    top:150px;
    display:none;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Code:

```
<div class="title">
  rid:<a 
    onmouseover="showCustomer(' + item.pid + ',' + item.rmid + ')" 
    onmouseout="hide()">' + item.rid + '</a></div><div id="showdata">
</div>

function hide() {
    document.getElementsById("showdata").style.display = "none";
}
```

When I mouse over `' + item.rid + '` it should display me the showdata div with content from db, but but it doesn't happen.

using inspect element  showcustomer has value  but it doesn't display  style.display = "block"

As well the query string for more than one parameter is correct?

```
"<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?        >/index.php/controller/action/id/"+s1+"&mid/"+s2**

function showCustomer(s1,s2) {
    document.getElementsById("showdata").style.display = "block";
    var xmlhttp;    

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
       }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?         >/index.php/controller/action/id/"+s1+"&mid/"+s2,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

But then the data from db is not fetched by ajax ..... this is not working ....

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;? >/index.php/controller/action/id/"+s1+"&mid/"+s2,true);
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in the code please?

Comment: Could it be that the request is asynchronous, and just hasn't appeared yet when you've already moved the mouse away from the item?

Comment: whats being thrown into showCustomer() it's got say + item.pid but hows this being set as to me its partial php code or js but if js it cannot be set

Comment: @Hans atleast the div should display that too is not working .......

Comment: @SimonDavies ya item.pid is retrieved from db and using jqouery am rendering using the foreach function .... and i did inspect the element it does contain the values in showcusomer the only thing not happing is ajax doesnt display div block on mouseover

Comment: @tisha thanks for the clarification :-) if using jquery why are you not using their $.ajax method as well?

Comment: @SimonDavies :) am yet not that strong in ajax its just my begining and i wanna use it onmouseover the one which i understood i have implemented ..... when am handy l go for it ...... for know i dont know the $.ajax method ...... can you code some sample here using $.ajax ...... with reference to my examples

Comment: @tisha have a quick look at http://jsfiddle.net/simondavies/6AbfX/1/ this might help but would need more explaining etc if you are not sure but not within this post/comment more details on it at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ hope this helps a little

Comment: @SimonDavies sorry for the late reply and thanks :) for the jsfiddle i did understood

Comment: @tisha no problem hope it helps and if you use that way let me knwo and i will add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked url to be provided must be correct had to use "/"
instead of "&"

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;? >/index.php/controller/action/id/"+s1+"/mid/"+s2,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code:

```
function showCustomer(s1,s2) {
    document.getElementsById("showdata").style.display = "block";
```

Should be

```
function showCustomer(s1,s2) {
    document.getElementById("showdata").style.display = "block";
```

(Plural - singular. getElementById is always singular since id is unique.)

Edit: And the same error is in your hide function

```
function hide() {
    document.getElementById("showdata").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: ya exactly thats such a silly thing i did ........ but then the data from db is not fetched by ajax ..... this is not working ....xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?         >/index.php/controller/action/id/"+s1+"&mid/"+s2,true);........

Comment: Not sure what the problem is there, but I can guess: PHP is resolved on the SERVER, and this code is already on the client. So your PHP code in the URL will not be resolved. Also, I think the way you build the URL is all wrong. Can you tell me what URL you are aiming to achieve? Maybe I can simplify things a bit.

Comment: exactly my url parameter passing was wrong .....the thing was my url doesnt have "&" it has "/"  and it worked:)     xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;? >/index.php/controller/action/id/"+s1+"/mid/"+s2,true);